# Error de sintaxis en Java, MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un error de sintaxis en el siguiente `String` y no sé a que es debido. Nparte es de tipo `int`.

```
String editSQL="UPDATE PARTESDETRABAJO SET DESCRIPCIONTAREA=?,"+"FECHAENTRADA=?,"+"FECHAENTREGA=?,"+"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?"+"WHERE NPARTE="+sesion.getAttribute("ENparte");
```

Me sale el siguiente error y no consigo solucionarlo, he pasado `sesion.getAttribute("ENparte")`a `int` y me peta, pero así como está el error es este:

> Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NPARTE=1'
>   at line 1

Comment: podrías en vez de usar la sesión, poner directamente un 1 a ver si funciona ? Si funciona quizás el problema es que el sesion realmente no sea un entero, si estás usando jsp aunque pongas 1, lo que guardas es "1" y necesitarás las comillas  en la select porque es un string.

Comment: Creo que es una errata: te falta un espacio en `...+"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?"+"<espacioaquí>WHERE NPARTE="+...`

Comment: He probado a ponerlo con comillas también

Comment: Haz un un `System.out.println` de `editSQL` y lo podrás ver mejor...

Comment: Parece ser que **son dos espacios los que faltan en vez de uno**, aquí: `"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?"+WHERENPARTE="+sesion.getAttribute("ENparte")`, es decir: `"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?"+"--->espacio aquí<---WHERE--->espacio aquí<---NPARTE="+sesion.getAttribute("ENparte")`. Por cierto, ¿por qué no usas también un marcador para el `WHERE` como haces con los otros valores?, el código sería mucho más seguro así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donde has escrito

```
"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?"+"WHERE NPARTE="
```

debes poner

```
"TIEMPOEMPLEADO=?"+" WHERE NPARTE="
```

No has dejado espacio antes del WHERE y por eso te está fallando la query.

Aunque si somos estrictos, no sé por qué parte la query en esa concatenación. Directamente podrías escribir

```
String editSQL="UPDATE PARTESDETRABAJO SET DESCRIPCIONTAREA=?, FECHAENTRADA=?, FECHAENTREGA=?, TIEMPOEMPLEADO=? WHERE NPARTE="+sesion.getAttribute("ENparte");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias fue por esto

Comment: No hay de qué. Márcala como respuesta correcta por si puede servirle para alguien en el futuro